# Linking two lists of words and categories with own corpus with python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Okay, I thought about it over and over again, but i'm just a beginner at python and I don't find any solution.
This is what i need to do: 
I've got a text file from LIWC with all kinds of Dutch words and numbers behind it:

```
aaien 12 13 32
aan 10
aanbad 12 13 14 57 58 38
...
```

Then I've got a text file from LIWC with a number and a category behind it:

```
01:Pronoun
02:I
03:We
04:Self
05:You
06:Other
...
```

And now I'm supposed to link my own corpus with Dutch words with these categories. So first I'll have to link my Dutch words with the numbers behind the Dutch words in the LIWC word list, and then I'll have to link those numbers with these categories... 
I thought it would be useful to make dictionaries of both lists from LIWC.
This is what i've got so far:

```
with open('LIWC_words.txt', 'rU') as document:
    answer = {}
    for line in document:
        line = line.split()
        if not line:  #empty line
            continue
        answer[line[0]] = line[1:]

with open ('LIWC_categories.txt','rU') as document1:
    categoriesLIWC = {}
    for line in document1:
        line = line.strip()
        if not line:
            continue
        key, value = line.split(':')
        if key.isdigit():
            categoriesLIWC[int(key)] = value
        else:
            categoriesLIWC[key] = value
```

So i've got two dictionaries now... But now I'm stuck. Does anyone has an idea what I should do next? (I work with python 2.6.5 because I have to work with NLTK mostly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what end format you are trying to create. You could, for example make a dictionary where `dict['pronoun']` contains all the lines from the `document` that have `'01'` in it.

```
#for example from this format
dic = {'word1': [1,2,3], 'word2':[3,2]}
ref = {1: 'pronoun', 2: 'I' , 3: 'you'}

out = {}

for word in dic:
  for entry in dic[word]:
    if entry in out:
      out[entry].append(word)
    else:
      out[entry] = []
      out[entry].append(word)

print out
>>>{1: ['word1'], 2: ['word1', 'word2'], 3: ['word1', 'word2']}
```

Or, you could replace the numbers in `document` with the entries in `document1`.

```
#for example from this format
dic = {'word1': [1,2,3], 'word2':[3,2]}
ref = {1: 'pronoun', 2: 'I' , 3: 'you'}

for word in dic:
  for indx in range(len(dic[word])): 
    dic[word][indx] = ref[dic[word][indx]]

print dic
>>>{'word1': ['pronoun', 'I', 'you'], 'word2': ['you', 'I']}
```

otherwise have you thought about a database?

Comment: {'word1': ['pronoun', 'I', 'you'], 'word2': ['you', 'I']} => I think this is what i need but when i run that code, python gives an error: KeyError: '39'

Comment: Is 39 defined in what I called the `ref` dictionary?

Comment: You might get around that with `if dic[word][indx] in ref:` after the second `for`. But this will leave the number as it was.

Comment: now it just gives me dic {'word1': [1,2,3], 'word2':[3,2]} again... Nothing changed

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to get the data into that format.

```
dic = {}
ref = {}
tempdic = open('dic.txt','r').read().split('\n')
tempref = open('ref.txt','r').read().split('\n')

for line in tempdic:
  if line:
    line = line.split()
    dic[line[0]] = line[1:]
for line in tempref:
  if line:
    line = line.split(':')
    ref[line[0]] = line[1]
#dic = {'word1':[1,2,3], word2:[2,3]...}
#ref = {1:'ref1',2:'ref2',...}
for word in dic:
  for indx in range(len(dic[word])):#for each number after word
    dic[word][indx] = ref[dic[word][indx]]
```

let's say we started with `{'apple':[1,2,3]}`. `dic['apple'][0]` would resolve to `1`, the right side would be `ref[1]` which could be `'pronoun'`. This would leave us with`{'apple' : ['pronoun', 2, 3]` with the remaining numbers to be replaced on the next iteration.